# My library is "empty" after publish with JitPack

Tags: android, android-library, jitpack

I trying to publish an Android library with JitPack as described at https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/ and https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin#groovy. The JitPack build logs show that everything is fine, I can import it to my project. But after building the project I can't access the library code. I literally can't see it, even in External Libraries.

Comment: Do you have minify enabled in your library? It might be stripping away all of your classes.

Comment: Hi @Pawel! I turned off minifyEnabled on my library.

Answer (score 1):

@Pawel's method work for me: `minifyEnabled false` in library build.gradle do the trick!

Comment: OMG, @Alesh17 you are my savior . I even didn't think about that. Thank you so much!